# Mule http request configuration proxy

Tags: web-services, mule, http-proxy, anypoint-studio

I'm following a tutorial from mulesoft ([DataWeave Tutorial](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-tutorial)) witch implements a Web Service Consumer that calls an external public web service ([WSDL](http://tshirt-service.cloudhub.io/?wsdl)). I had no problem to setup the project as described, but when I launch my server I have the following error: "Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect".

First thought was that the webservice was unavailable. But I tested it in SoapUI and it workded just fine.

I suppose the error is because the call to the web service is not using the proxy configurations that I have set up in Anypoint Studio. So, in my Web Service Consumer I have set up a HTTP Request Configuration where I added a Proxy Configuration. But it also did not work. Those were my steps:

Web Service Consumer

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN584.png
```

References tab

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIV84.png
```

HTTP Request Configuration

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ubpwa.png
```

Proxy tab

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBYx1.png
```

Proxy Configuration

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQdf.png
```

One thing that is immediately noticeable is the the TLS error on the HTTP Request Configuration. This error appears as soon as I choose to use a proxy and when I go to the TLS/SSL tab I have no option to remove the TLS configuration as you can see in the following image:

TLS/SSL tab

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFqEW.png
```

Here's the XML of my flow:

```
    <flow name="dataweave_tutorialFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="ex1" doc:name="HTTP" metadata:id="b34a6c34-653f-4b68-8aa3-8292e41a20cf"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:input-payload doc:sample="C:\temp\dw_example1.json"/>
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
        %output application/xml
        %namespace ns0 http://mulesoft.org/tshirt-service
        ---
        {
            ns0#OrderTshirt: {
                size: "M" unless payload.buyer.state == "TX" otherwise "XXL",
                email: payload.buyer.email,
                name: payload.buyer.name,
                address1: payload.buyer.address,
                address2: null,
                city: payload.buyer.city,
                stateOrProvince: payload.buyer.state,
                postalCode: payload.buyer.postCode,
                country: payload.buyer.nationality
            }
        }]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Tshirt" operation="OrderTshirt" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
</flow>
```

I'm using Anypoint Studio 6.2.5 with Mule ESB Server 3.8.2.

I have no more ideas for what to change to make this work. Hope anyone has some good suggestion about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just noticed that I forgot to put some important parts of the XML before the flow, but those configurations are available on the images that I have posted.

Comment: pls update our question with full config ... your proxy conf is not visible

Comment: Configurations are visible on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQdf.png)
Configuration are the following:
Proxy Configuration Name: XXXXX_PROXY_CONFIG
Host: http://proxywbs.int.XXXXX.com
Port: 8080

Comment: And the proxy configurations of my company are correct, I use them in many other places.

Answer (score 0):

You dont require to mention **http** in proxy url host can set the proxy using following example:-

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="www.webservicex.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration">
     <http:proxy host="my.example.proxy.com" port="8080"/>
</http:request-config>
```

You may need to provide your proxy username and password based on your proxy.
A best example is if you follow step by step written here :-
http://www.corralict.nl/wsc-connector-proxy/
and
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/web-service-consumer

Regarding `tls`, don't touch the `tls` part and make sure your HTTP request protocol is set to HTTP and not HTTPS. The error you are seeing is a **bug** in studio and will not affect if you configure rightly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried with and without the **http** on the proxy host and it makes no difference, I still can't make it work. And I don't need authentication on my proxy server, host and port it's all it takes.
The first link you sent is perfect, it explains exactly what I'm doing. I tried out this example on my Anypoint Studio and once again I had the same problem. 
It seems that I'm doing my configurations just right, I'm wondering if it can't be a bug on any of the versions I'm using...

Comment: If feel so, raise a jira ticket here https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/projects/MULE/issues